# why lsb_release command not working on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to find the Ubuntu OS version, so I executed the command

```
lsb_release –a
```

But I am gettig below error:

```
Usage: lsb_release [options]
lsb_release: error: No arguments are permitted
```

The uname output
uname -a

```
Linux LX-25TMXH2 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to upgrade the OS version to 18.04. I am not able to understand the current version as the command lsb command is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

In order to see the release of a Linux platform, you don't need LSB-release, you can just do this:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: its fine, we can conclude the loop. cat /etc/os-release also does the same thing. So no worries

Answer (score 1):

`lsb_release` is a Python script and is normally located at `/usr/bin`.

According to your description, I doubt it's because `lsb_release` is interpreted by the wrong Python.

Make sure the `lsb_release` is interpreted by the right version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a strange character in the command. I copied it from your question and got the same result you did. Then I typed it in myself and got the correct result. The 'dash' character looks a little different.

Copied from the question

```sh
$ lsb_release –a
Usage: lsb_release [options]
lsb_release: error: No arguments are permitted
```

Typed it myself

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```